# creating mysql index

Tags: mysql

I have query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM _mod_news USE INDEX ( ind1 )  WHERE show_lv =1 AND active =1 AND START <= NOW( ) 
AND ( END >= NOW( )  OR END =  "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ) AND id <>  "18041" AND category_id =  "3" AND leta =1 ORDER BY sort_id ASC , DATE DESC  LIMIT 7
```

result:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  _mod_news   ref ind1    ind1    2   const,const 11386   Using where; Using filesort
```

mysql is performing full table scan

ind1 =

```
ALTER TABLE `_mod_news` ADD INDEX ind1 ( `show_lv`, `active`,  `start`, `end`, `id`, `category_id`, `leta`, `sort_id`, `date`);
```

I tested on following index, but nothing changes

```
ALTER TABLE `_mod_news` ADD INDEX ind1 ( `show_lv`, `active`,  `start`, `end`, `id`, `category_id`, `leta`);
```

Question is: where i can learn how to create indexes on many where conditions? Or someone can explain how to tell to mysql to use and index and not to scan whole table.
Thanks.

Comment: All columns in your `WHERE` clause need to be on the index for an index to be used.

Comment: i already have that index. maybe mysql don't like `OR` ?

Comment: You may need to use tick marks around reserved words such as `END`.

Comment: How distinct are the fields you have in the where clause?

Comment: date and integer columns

Comment: You need to post the EXPLAIN.  It will tell you how much of the index is being used.  MySQL likes to ignore indexes when date ranges get large.  You may benefit from moving the other integer values to be earlier in the composite index.

Your first index would keep MySQL from having to read the underlying rows to perform the ORDER BY.  It may be doing this anyway, since you're doing a SELECT *, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not forcing index. Mysql is a great at selecting the best possible index unless you have better understanding of the data you are querying.

You cannot use ORDER BY optimization because you are mixing the ASC and DESC in that part.

Therefore your only option is to create index such that:

- constant values before range
- integers before dates, dates before strings, smaller size vales before bigger size values

Creating a large index also adds an overhead to storage and insert-update time, so i would not add to index fields that are not eliminating a lot of rows (i.e 90% or rows have a value of 1 or i.e `id<>"18041"` but that most likely eliminates < 1% of rows).

If you want to learn more about optimizing: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-optimization.html

Create multiple different indexes (on decent size of data you expect seeing in the table), see which one mysql chooses, benchmark them by forcing each one of them, then use your common sense to cut down on index space usage.

You can see from you EXPLAIN output that it is actually NOT performing a full table scan because in that case it would not display it using the index even when you are forcing it.

Comment: Thanks. But rows = 11386, that means that mysql is operating with 11386 rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with USE INDEX or [FORCE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html)

Comment: i already have `use index` and explain is showing that `ind1` is used.